# Convert pandoc-style citations to the LaTeX cite format

Tags: bibtex, citing, pandoc, markdown

I have a Markdown document with pandoc-style citations such as `[@johndoe2014]`. This documents needs to be converted to LaTeX for submission to a scientific journal. The LaTeX template of the journal stipulates the use of the `cite` package, and asks to avoid using additional packages for compatibility purposes.

I am aware that using `--biblatex` or `--natbib` options with pandoc, one can convert pandoc-style citations to one of these styles, in our example to `\autocites{johndoe2014}`.

Would it be possible to automatically convert pandoc-style citations to the `cite` format, e.g. `\cite{johndoe2014}`? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but what's stopping you from doing a 'replace all' autocites->cite in your editor or writing a script to do the same?

Comment: ...or you could simply put `\let\autocites=\cite` into your preamble and don't worry about doing a replace-all.

Comment: Can you present a small example?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the `--natbib` option produces `\autocites{<key>}` since that is not a `natbib` command.  Can you be more precise about how you are calling `pandoc`?

Comment: @jon `\autocites` pertains to `biblatex`, of course, which I have mentioned along with `natbib`.

Comment: @Mass @Andrew a replacement could work in theory, but the complication is that `cite` and `biblatex` handle citations for multiple authors differently. That is, `\autocites{johndoe2014}{janedoe2014}` vs `\cite{johndoe2014,janedoe2014}`. Is there a workaround for that as well, perhaps?

Comment: Right.  What I was implicitly suggesting was to *not* use the `--biblatex` option but the `--natbib` option.  Regarding the `\autocites{johndoe2014}{janedoe2014}` issue, that could also be solved with utitlities like `sed`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in feature in pandoc that compiles pandoc-style citations to the `cite` package format. A quick workaround would be to first use the `--natbib` flag in pandoc to convert to `natbib`:

```
pandoc article.md -s --natbib -o article.tex
```

and then use the following `sed` commands to rename all the citations from `\citet` and `\citep` to `\cite` as well as change the `natbib` package in the preamble to `cite`:

```
sed -i 's/\\cite[t,p]{/\\cite{/g' article.tex
sed -i 's/{natbib}/{cite}/' article.tex
```

If you want to avoid overwriting your original .tex file, you can pipe successive `sed` calls and save to a new file:

```
sed 's/\\cite[t,p]{/\\cite{/g' article.tex | sed 's/{natbib}/{cite}/' > article-new.tex
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using another journal which accepted natbib. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: For Mac OS X, `-i` should be replaced with `-ie` in order to provide a zero-length extension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486667/sed-without-backup-file

Comment: Or `brew install coreutils` then use `gsed` instead of `sed` for the GNU version